# Does referencing a singleton's sharedInstance create a retain cycle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, retain-cycle

Say I have the following singleton:

```
@interface ABCSingleton: NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) ABCViewController *mainViewController;
@end

@implementation ABCSingleton
+ (ABCSingleton *)sharedInstance {
    static ABCSingleton *instance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [ABCSingleton new];
    });
    return instance;
}
- (void)doSomething {
}
@end
```

If *doSomething* contained this code:

```
- (void)doSomething {
    self.mainViewController.tapBlock = ^() {
        self.name = @"abc";
    };
}
```

... it would create a retain cycle since ABCSingleton owns mainViewController, which owns tapBlock, which owns ABCSingleton.

What if instead of using *self*, I used *sharedInstance*?

```
- (void)doSomething {
    self.mainViewController.tapBlock = ^() {
        [ABCSingleton sharedInstance].name = @"abc";
    };
}
```

Would it still create a retain cycle? (An explanation as to why, or why not, would be appreciated!)

Comment: That will cause a retain cycle, but you should ask yourself whether a retain cycle on a singleton matters. You defined a strong static reference to it, so it's never going away.

Comment: @Fabian: Good point, I updated the example to show why I'm specifically looking not to create a retain cycle. I don't want mainViewController to remain in memory forever.

Comment: Again, the retain cycle is irrelevant. 
`@property (nonatomic, strong) ABCViewController *mainViewController;` will make it so that `mainViewController` is never released unless you explicitly nil it out somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

To the specific question, this is a retain loop in the first case, and equivalent to a retain loop in the second case (equivalent in that `mainViewController` will never be released).

This indicates a deeper design problem. A singleton should never reference a view controller. Singletons are by nature model objects. Model objects should never reference controller objects directly. See [Model-View-Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) for an introduction. This is a key design pattern in Cocoa.

Instead, the view controller should know about the model (the singleton in this case). `doSomething` should modify the model, and the view controller, when it comes on the screen, should read the model to set `tapBlock`. The view controller can also observe the model (via KVO, notifications, or delegation) while it is onscreen to know when to change its values.